# Room stops to insert after the 2nd insert into the database on the phone disk

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Whenever I insert something into the database, the first two inserts pass through and save in the disk. By using "Android Debug Database" I can inspect the inserted rows and see that it was successful.

The 3rd insert is where it always stuck. No matter how many inserts follow afterwards, they never save in the disk. Never until I restart the app and whoops things run again then it starts over and stops inserting after the 2nd insert. I actually debugged my app in every possible way. The payload was correct each time. Matter of fact, the insert is successful to. If I run a query and fetch the rows (SELECT *), it gives me back three inserts. All three. However, in the disk, it still only displays two inserts. If I restart the app and run the query again and fetch the rows (SELECT *), it turns back to two.

It seems like the problem seems to be persistent on some low level because my code is right. It was also the reason why I haven't posted it here. Believe me it has been checked multiple times.

I just need the answer, why does it stop transmitting the data from the cache into the database on the phone disk after the 2nd insert?

Comment: My guess is that your problem lies with whatever "Android Debug Database" is. You are welcome to examine the generated Java code in your `build/` directory to see what Room is doing. It is not caching inserts. Depending on how your code is written, those inserts might be asynchronous... but since you declined to provide a [mcve], nobody can help you with that, or with much of anything else with your question.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, good suggestion but I quote "If I restart the app and run the query again and fetch the rows (SELECT *), it turns back to two.". So the "Android Debug Database" by "Amitshekhariitbhu" ain't the issue here.

Comment: Sorry -- I interpreted "it turns back to two" as meaning "I can do another two inserts before things get strange again".

Comment: Both apply. You can do another 2 inserts. After it the rest only caches. I can fetch them from the cache with (SELECT *), it tells me I have 4, 5 rows. I restart the app, it tells me I have 2 rows because the cache never dumped the other inserts into the phone disk (.db file).